# How to dynamically invoke a class based on a string?

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, interface

Can you give me some guidance to dynamically load class based on name. The name is provided as a argument at runtime.

```
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        ...
    }
```

Let's say my argument is "parrot" then I would like to load my `parrotProcessor` class. If my argument name is "snake" then I load my To make `snakeProcessor`. Of course this mean I have a parrot and snake processor class that inherit an interface IProcessor. I don't know what could be the list of all processor. this list is maintained by other developers and they can create what they want.

Example of my processor interface:

```
    public interface IProcessor
    {
        void Process();
    }
```

And in my Program.cs

```
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var processor = GetProcessor(args[0]);
        processor.Process();
    }
```

My question is what should I do in `GetProcessor()` method?

Here is what I have at this moment:

```
    private IProcessor GetProcessor(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
             case "ant":
                return new AntProcessor();
             case "parrot":
                return new ParrotProcessor();
             case "snake":
                return new SnakeProcessor();
             default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Case not found");
        }
    }
```

But this mean I must updated this ugly switch each time I create a new processor specialized class. This is not possible. I can do it now for development but not for long term.

What are the solutions? Should I use something similar to DI with NInject or am I mixing everything? Can I simply use the Invoke method? And why Invoke or DI? I know this question is kind of open question but it is something that happen often in code of many people so I suppose there is unique best practice about it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like the following

```
var type = Type.GetType("MyFullyQualifiedTypeName");
var myObject = (MyAbstractClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

You need to do some string modifications like taking the word, adding the processor string and making sure that all the processors are at the same place.

If you are certain that the type is in the current assembly, simply fully qualified name by this

```
 Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("SomeProcessor"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try iterate over all exported types in specific assembly:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Assembly assembly = typeof (Program).Assembly; // use current assembly...

            var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes() // public types only
                                .Where (type => type.GetInterfaces().Contains (typeof (IProcessor))) // interface must be implemented
                                .Where (type => type.Name.EndsWith ("Processor")) // and maybe use some naming convention?
                                .ToList();

            //string name = args[0];
            string name = "Parrot";

            Type parrotType = types.Where (x => x.Name.StartsWith (name)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (parrotType != null)
            {
                // it will work only when we implement parameterless constructor for this type
                IProcessor parrotInstance = (IProcessor) Activator.CreateInstance (parrotType);
                parrotInstance.Process();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IProcessor
    {
        void Process();
    }

    public class SnakeProcessor : IProcessor
    {
        public void Process()
        {
        }
    }

    public class ParrotProcessor : IProcessor
    {
        public void Process()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Parrot Process");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is absolutely nothing wrong with using a `switch` block as you are doing. It gets the job done, and it serves as an explicit source of truth with regards to the interpretation of the command-line parameter. It also acts as a whitelist, preventing users from passing a class name that maybe you don't want them to instantiate. Yes, you have to update it every time you add a new class, but you're already adding the class itself, so you are already in a situation where a new version and deployment will be needed.

That being said, there are various reasons why you'd rather have the ability to look up a command line parameter and automatically know which type to instantiate. That is trivial to do with a `Dictionary<string,Func<IProcessor>>`:

```
this.Map = new Dictionary<string,Func<IProcessor>>
{
    { "ant", () => new AntProcessor() },
    { "snake", () => new SnakeProcessor() },
    { "parrot", () => new ParrotProcessor() },
    { "lizard", () => new LizardProcessor() }
};
```

Then you would handle a command-line parameter like this:

```
//Use the string to look up a delegate
var ok = this.Map.TryGetValue(textFromCommandline, out var func);  

//If not found, user entered a bad string
if (!ok) throw new ArgumentException();

//Invoke the delegate to obtain a new instance 
IProcessor processor = func(); 

return processor;
```

Once you understand the concept of using a map in this way, you can come up with a scheme to populate it automatically, e.g

```
this.Map = assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where( t => typeof(IProcessor).IsAssignableFrom( t ))
    .ToDictionary
    (
        t => t.Name, 
        t => new Func<IProcessor>( () => Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IProcessor );
    );
```

And you will have met your goal of not having to maintain a hardcoded list anywhere.

Comment: typeof(IProcessor).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IProcessor)) == true

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite `private IProcessor GetProcessor(string name)` method using a little mix of reflection and LINQ like this:

```
 private IProcessor GetProcessor<Tinterface>(string name) where Tinterface : IProcessor
 {
      var type = typeof(Tinterface).Assembly.GetTypes()
                                   .First(x => x.FullName.Contains("name"));
      return (Tinterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
 }
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    var processor = GetProcessor<IProcessor>(args[0]);
    processor.Process();
}
```

This route saves you the stress of typing the fully qualified name of the class

Comment: I'd add `GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(Tinterface).IsAssignableFrom(t))`

Comment: That addition looks very interesting. @JeremyLakeman I'm eager to know how that will improve the method.

Comment: It would prevent attempting to create any random class, that could do something unexpected in it's constructor, before hitting a cast exception. Also, you should probably change the criteria to `.First(x => x.Name == name)`

Answer (score 2):

I will add to the answers that suggest using reflection : EX: `IProcessor parrotInstance = (IProcessor) Activator.CreateInstance(parrotType);` is to make this part of code in a separate Factory class for Processor this way you can reuse the factory class in other places in your code, also even if you decide to keep the `switch` statement, the changes on the factory class will only affect it without affecting any dependent code.

```
public interface IProcessorFactory
{
    IProcessor GetProcessor(string processorTypeName);
}
```

Good read:
[SOLID Design Principles](https://www.dotnetforall.com/solid-design-principles-examples/)